# assign values instead of filtering in RStudio mistake

Tags: r

I am using RStudio Version 1.1.456 with Windows 10. I was trying to filter one of the columns, year after I open a data frame but then I ended up assigning values.

`data$Year = 1960`

Is there a way to go back or any way to fix it or is re-opening the data frame and re-run codes is only solution.

Comment: There's no undo assignment, re-run the code. That mistake in particular happens to everybody.

Comment: Thanks I am new to using RStudio so I wasn't sure if there is a way to quickly fix it or just re-run everything.

Comment: It is not about RStudio, it's about assignments in general. Once done they can't be undone. The previous value is lost.